# Open cv c++: How to split video several part by time?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, split

I would like to ask you how to split video (.mp4) on several videos by open cv (language c++) by time? For example I have video 10 seconds long and I want to create two videos from it; the first video captures frames from original video between 0 second and 5 seconds and the second video captures frames from original video between 6 seconds and 10 seconds.
Is there somebody who knows answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the inputVideo and calculate how many frames you need.

Then write the number of frames to the first output video and the rest to the second.

Something like this should work

```
for(;;) //Show the image captured in the window and repeat
{
    countFirstVideo++;
    inputVideo >> src;              // read
    if (src.empty()){ break;  }       // check if at end
    if(countFirstVideo++ < myDesignatedSize)
    {
      outputVideo1 << src;
    }
    else
    {
      outputVideo2 << src;
    }
}
```